# MySQL SELECT statement inside CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

I have a `PRODUCTS` table which contains product records or subproducts records.  Subproducts are indicated by having an entry in the `HIGHERCATALOGID` column, while for products the `HIGHERCATALOGID` column is NULL.  I'm trying to write a query that would output product name if catalogid is pointing to a product record, or name of the parent product if catalogid is pointing to a subproduct.  Here is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT p.catalogid, p.highercatalogid, oi.orderid
CASE
    WHEN highercatalogid is null then cname\
ELSE
    SELECT cname from products p1 where p.highercatalogid=p1.catalogid
END as name
FROM products p, oitems oi
WHERE p.catalogid=oi.catalogid
```

However, this results in an error.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case  WHEN highercatalogid is null then cname else  select cname from products p' at line 2

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it this way

```sql
SELECT p.catalogid, p.highercatalogid, oi.orderid,
       COALESCE(p2.cname, p.cname) cname
  FROM oitems oi JOIN products p
    ON oi.catalogid = p.catalogid LEFT JOIN products p2
    ON p.highercatalogid = p2.catalogid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/571028/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you!  I was not familiar with COALESCE operator, and it's exactly what the doctor ordered.

Comment: @user3358413 if this answers your question, best is if you then accept the answer clicking on the tick mark top left of the answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.catalogid, p.highercatalogid, oi.orderid
```

> ,

```
CASE
WHEN highercatalogid is null then cname
ELSE
SELECT cname from products p1 where p.highercatalogid=p1.catalogid
END as name
FROM products p, oitems oi 
WHERE p.catalogid=oi.catalogid
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining that the issue is the missing `,` after `oi.orderid`, it'll be clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm modified my answer